# What do I need to write device drivers on Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, development, source-code

What do I need to write device drivers on Ubuntu? Do I need source code for Linux? What else is needed?

Comment: Did you solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the "Linux Device Drivers" book at O'Reilly. It's a very common reference and it is really written in a way that explains the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a set of links which you might find interesting. Good Luck!!! and happy coding!

1. [freesoftwaremagazine](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux) (slightly outdated)
2. Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition never read it but i hear some good things about it [order](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005900) or read as a [pdf online](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)
3. [Essential Linux Device Drivers](http://books.google.com/books?id=Boo57V0IOq0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
4. [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment) wiki about the development of Ubuntu. good two know
5. [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/)

**Source**:

[Are there recommended tutorials for writing drivers for Gnu/Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629129/are-there-recommended-tutorials-for-writing-drivers-for-gnu-linux/)